# Does solving Sudoku puzzles improve your mental abilities?

Tags: intelligence

A lot of people I know see solving Sudoku puzzles as a way to train their minds.

[howtoincreasememorypower.com](http://www.howtoincreasememorypower.com/a-sudoku-a-day-exercises-the-brain/) recommends doing a Sudoku puzzle a day to increase brain power.

> Researchers rank solving sudoku puzzles daily among the top ten non-traditional and alternative ways to boosts brain power.

...

> They stress that just as physical exercise keeps muscle loss at bay, sudoku exercise keeps brain cells from dying and also encourages better brain function. Education is important, but studies actually show that students who do mental workouts like sudoku have higher IQs than students who do not. This only shows that doses of sudoku are more than just ways to pass time. They actually help in improving your ability to comprehend more complex ideas.

...

> Other experts agree with these findings, saying that solving challenging mind games like sudoku puzzles inhibit or prevent the development of Alzheimer’s disease and memory loss. Health trends also show that adults with demanding, and intellectually challenging jobs benefit from better mental function when they age. Sudoku functions just like these jobs because it requires brain exertions.

Is there evidence that solving puzzles like Sudoku provide good mental training?

Comment: The evidence *I* collected suggests strongly that they are boring :)

Comment: -1 Sorry, I just think the question body could have a little more text that explains the connection with skepticism or the claim being refuted.

Comment: +1 I think it stands fine on its own. I did post an edit that I think might help. It doesn't expand the body much but makes the question a little more pointed.

Comment: Bah, I don't know the sources, so I'm just posting a comment. I've heard of research (I think it was The Guardian's Science Weekly podcast, way back) that pointed to the contrary: solving sudokus will make you better at solving sudokus, but the skill doesn't seem to transfer to other tasks.

Comment: I don't think *mental training* is sufficiently well-defined to provide a worthwhile answer. A more answerable question might be "Does regular Sudoku exercise stave off mental decline in people at risk for age-related mental illness?" or "Does Sudoku exercise make you faster/more accurate at doing tasks other than Sudoku?"

Comment: I would be astonished if it does, as Sudoku is a very mechanical puzzle which requires very little cognitive ability. It is very difficult to fail to complete a Sudoku, but also very boring. I would expect other puzzles such as Kakuro, Killer etc which require more calculation, probability assessment etc to be much better for the brain.

Comment: @Rory Alsop: try the more difficult ones, some are practically unsolvable if you're just following rules mechanically without at least some insight.

Comment: I agree with @Timwi and @Rory.  Once you know a few simple tricks, solving sudokus becomes quite simple.  Sure there are probably some difficult ones out there that are hand crafted by people to be very easy to solve. However, most of the Sudokus you see out there are extremely simple.  Also, the rules of Sudoku specifically state that you don't have to guess, making the puzzle that much easier.  If you at some point had to make guesses, and then your wrong guess would cause you to back track, then the puzzles would be much more difficult in my opinion.

Comment: @Kibbee IIRC, the puzzles can be solved deterministically. The point of Sudoku puzzles is getting them done ASAP.

Comment: Not sure, I would like to believe that I am exercising my grey matter. There is a great personal reward upon completing a difficult puzzle. Then the high is over and start another one ( no wonder they call sudoku the crack cocaine of puzzles ). Hey I'm not hurting anyone, get over it !

Comment: Well, solving Sudoku puzzles definitely makes you better at solving Sudoku puzzles.

Answer (score 30):

[**No Gain From Brain Training**](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v464/n7292/full/4641111a.html)

> The [largest trial](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v465/n7299/abs/nature09042.html) to date of
> 'brain-training' computer games
> suggests that people who use the
> software to boost their mental skills
> are likely to be disappointed.
>
> **A total of 11,430 volunteers aged from
> 18 to 60 completed the study**, and
> although they improved on the tasks,
> the researchers believe that none of
> the groups boosted their performance
> on tests measuring general cognitive
> abilities such as memory, reasoning
> and learning.

> [image: Statistics]
>
> Although improvements were observed in every one of the cognitive tasks that were trained, **no evidence was found for transfer effects to untrained tasks, even when those tasks were cognitively closely related**.

The study has been criticized, though: [[1](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v464/n7292/full/4641111a.html)], [[2](http://www.time.com/time/health/article/0,8599,1983306,00.html#ixzz0lh0ZMO77)], [[3](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748703763904575196400381395576.html?mod=WSJ_latestheadlines)]

---

[**Scientific American - Do Brain Trainer Games and Software Work?**](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=brain-trainings-unproven-hype)

> **Neuroscientist [Peter Snyder](http://research.brown.edu/research/profile.php?id=1229013784) of Brown University [reviewed nearly 20 software studies](http://www.alzheimersanddementia.com/article/S1552-5260%2808%2902922-1/abstract) and concluded that, as a group, they were underwhelming**.
>
> They are marred by flaws that induce confounding factors, such as a lack of control groups and follow-up, Snyder warns.
>
> More than a third of those he reviewed were too shoddy even to include in the analysis he printed early this year in the journal [*Alzheimer’s & Dementia*](http://www.alzheimersanddementia.com/home).
>
> **One paper, however, exceeded expectations**: in a new study Snyder called the “most well-designed” of those he evaluated, [the Mayo Clinic tested the Brain Fitness Program](http://www.mayoclinic.org/news2009-rst/5179.html) by [Posit Science](http://www.positscience.com/).
>
> Encour­agingly, **the researchers found that the software boosted the brain in ways unrelated to the training**. Rather than simply learning to parrot back what they had practiced, participants improved their test scores across a range of brain functions, says clinical neuropsychologist [Glenn Smith](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/biography/SB00028), who led the study.
>
> Still, **the boost was minimal**. Subjects who played improved their memory by twice as much as did those in the control group (who spent an equal amount of time watching educational documentaries). **After eight weeks of training, that improvement was only about 4 percent**.

---

There have been [studies](http://www.alzheimersweekly.com/content/sharpening-your-wits-could-outwit-alzheimers) that suggest that mentally stimulating activities in old age helps reduce the risk of **Alzheimer's disease/dementia**.

> "The more you do mentally stimulating
> activities -- such as crossword
> puzzles or playing chess -- the better
> it is," said [Dr. Joe Verghese](http://www.einstein.yu.edu/faculty/profile.asp?id=5323), an
> assistant professor of neurology at
> Albert Einstein College of Medicine in
> New York City.
>
> Verghese recently co-authored a **study
> that found that seniors who engage in
> a wide variety of mental pursuits
> while at leisure** -- such as playing a
> musical instrument, reading and
> playing cards or board-games -- **seem
> to dramatically lower their risk for
> developing dementia**.
>
> But he stressed that it's never too
> early to incorporate mental exercise
> into the daily planner. In fact, it's
> a habit that should be encouraged
> starting in childhood, experts say.
>
> - [Leisure Activities and the Risk of Dementia in the Elderly](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa022252)
> - [Leisure Activities And The Risk of Amnestic Mild Cognitive Impairment In The Elderly](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1415273/)

---

But Crossword puzzles and other mentally stimulating pursuits [may just hide](http://au.news.yahoo.com/thewest/lifestyle/a/-/health/7869444/crossword-puzzles-may-hide-alzheimers/), rather than prevent, the progress of Alzheimer.

> Researchers in the US said the reality
> could be that, even without symptoms,
> the brain was suffering progressive
> damage behind the scenes.
>
> Mentally stimulating activities might
> help the brain "rewire" itself to
> circumvent the effects of dementia.
> However, once the disease was
> diagnosed, damage to the brain was
> likely to be greater than it would be
> in someone who was not mentally
> stimulated.
>
> [Dr Robert Wilson](http://www.rush.edu/rumc/page-1099611539759.html), from Rush University Medical Centre in Chicago, said **the research team's results suggested that the benefit of delaying the initial signs of cognitive decline might come at the cost of more rapid dementia progression later**.
>
> The 12-year-study involved evaluating the mental activity of 1157 people aged 65 and over - none of whom had dementia at the start of the study.
>
> - [ABC - Brain training linked to faster dementia progress](http://www.abc.net.au/worldtoday/content/2010/s3000571.htm)

---

**More:**

- [Nature - Do games improve mental performance?](http://www.nature.com/news/2008/080428/full/news.2008.784.html)
- [The Telegraph - Research suggests brain training for babies works](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/journalists/laura-donnelly/8771157/Research-suggests-brain-training-for-babies-works.html)
- [Can training in a real-time strategy video game attenuate cognitive decline in older adults?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19140648)

Comment: +1 this was the study I was referring to in comments, and it really does seem like the most rigorous take on the subject.

Comment: Many of the beneficial activities (e.g. playing cards) are social activities: which sudoku isn't. *Social* activity is stimulating.